# WSO2 DSS WSDLPrefix in clustered setup

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-data-services-server

I see no mention of setting up WSDL prefix in the clustering guide for DSS. I have setup for ESB and it works fine. Is it OK for me to use the same axis2.xml changes in DSS to make that prefix etc work in DSS cluster too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WSDLPrefix property is not required for DSS. In DSS there is no worker manager separation so you can skip this config for DSS.

Comment: ah - right. DSS seems a bit different to ESB then - I have changed the <HostName> in carbon.xml to my load balancer name to make the Endpoints direct there - hopefully it does not break anything